# $\mu(E)=\mu(\theta^{-1}(E)) \forall E \in \mathbb{E} \Rightarrow \mu(A)=\mu(\theta^{-1}(A)) \forall A \in \mathbb{A}$ for generator E and measure \mu

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have to prove the following:

Let $(S,\mathbb{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $\mathbb{A}=\sigma(\mathbb{E})$ for an $\cap$-stable generator $\mathbb{E}$. Further let $\theta: S \to S$ be a function with $\theta^{-1}(A) \in \mathbb{A} \forall A \in \mathbb{A}$ . show that:

$\mu(E)=\mu(\theta^{-1}(E)) \forall E \in \mathbb{E} \Rightarrow \mu(A)=\mu(\theta^{-1}(A)) \forall A \in \mathbb{A}$

---

my ideas:

I think i have to show that $D=( A\in \mathbb{A}: \mu(A)=\mu(\theta^{-1}(A)))$ is a Dynkin-System:

But I'm already failing to show that $S\in D$

Would need a little help here. Is my idea with the $\pi$-System correct?

Edit: Would I need the condition $S\in \mathbb{E}$? I have the feeling that this is missing...

Comment: I think $S$ is supposed to be same as $E$; $\theta^{-1}(E)=E$ so $E \in D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can use the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem of Dynkin to prove this fact. Note that because $\mathbb{E}$ is stable under intersections means that it is a $\pi-$system. To show that what you wrote as $D$ is a Dynkin system, we have the following:

i) $S \in D$: indeed, $\theta^{-1}(S) = S$ and of course $\mu(S) = \mu(\theta^{-1}(S));$

ii) let $A \in D.$ Then $\theta^{-1}(A^C) = (\theta^{-1}(A))^C$ and since $\mu$ is a finite measure we get $$\mu(A^C) = \mu(S) - \mu(A) = \mu(S) - \mu(\theta^{-1}(A)) = \mu((\theta^{-1}(A)^C) = \mu(\theta^{-1}(A^C));$$

iii) let $(A_n)_{n \geq 1} \subseteq D$ be an increasing sequence of sets. Then by the continuity of measure we get $$\mu(\cup_{n} A_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\theta^{-1}(A_n)) = \mu (\theta^{-1}(\cup_n A_n))$$ since we also have $\theta^{-1}(A_n) \subseteq \theta^{-1}(A_{n + 1})$ for $n \geq 1.$

This proves that $D$ is a Dynkin system and since $\mathbb{E} \subseteq D$ by assumption, the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem implies that $\mathbb{A} = \sigma(\mathbb{E}) \subseteq D,$ which concludes our proof. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: How can we be sure about $\theta^{-1}(S)=S$?

Comment: From the definition of the preimage of a function: $\theta^{-1}(S) := \{x \in S: \theta(x) \in S\}.$ Obviously, all of $S$ is mapped into $S$ by definition.

Comment: in iii) do we  need $(A_n)_{n\ge 1}$ to be disjoint sets?? Because then an increasing sequence is not possible?

Comment: No, of course we don't need the sets to be disjoint. If we would have needed disjoint sets, I would have mentioned something about that. I would suggest you spend a little time and familiarise yourself with the notion of Dynkin systems, for example from [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system).